# Best approach for collect money vs resolve some points

Tags: savings, spending, paper-money

First of all Sorry about my English.

Second I have this question: I don't know how to distribute money between goals that must be achieved(bought) at the certain time not now.
List of goals(it's example):

1. Laptop 1500$ 2-3 months
2. Bed 500$ 1-2 months
3. Table 700$ 4 months

For example now I have 1500$ and I want to save some money but at same time I want to bought something from list.  What is best approach to this situation?

- 1) I can buy Table or Bed and save money
- 2) I can buy Laptop but save
  nothing

May be exist other options in this situation?
I will be glad to hear all suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing right or wrong about this.

On such a short goals, you are essentially saying you need $2700 in next 4 months to buy 3 items. Essentially you can have sub-goals to save $675 each month.

As you already have some funds; you can go by priority buy the bed and then once you have more saved, buy the laptop and then buy the bed.

If you buy the bed now, it means that you will have to wait more for the laptop.

If the goals are further apart; say something in few months and something in few years, you would have to create to separate buckets to save and contribute proportionately to both the buckets.